# Emacs changes buffer when autosaving other window using tramp

Tags: emacs, autosave, tramp

I have two windows open in my Emacs session. Both are remote files opened using tramp. I make a change in window A and switch to window B without saving file in window A. When Emacs decides to autosave, the buffer displayed in window B is switched to the buffer from window A that was autosaved. This only happens when using tramp, not local files.

Another thing I have noticed is, that if I have the same file opened in two windows, because I need to reference something at another position in the file and save the file, the buffer I'm in sometimes jumps to the position that the point is in the other window, so I have to move around to get back to the place where I was editing.

Is this a bug or is there some setting that I have(n't) set? I suspect it is something related to refreshing the windows when saving.

i'm using Emacs 24.3 on OSX, but I have seen this using Linux too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds very much like a bug, to me.  Can you reproduce this starting from `emacs -Q` (i.e., with no init file)?

If so, use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to give Emacs Dev the recipe. If not, bisect your init file recursively until you locate the culprit code. Then ask for more help here, if it's not clear how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I can't reproduce without init file. I have thought that it might be something in there, but I couldn't see anything obvious. I think I'll comment everything out and then re-enable things step by step to see when it messes up again.

Comment: Excellent.  But don't re-enable things one at a time. Use binary search: Comment out 1/2 of the file, then 3/4, then 7/8, then 15/16...  Use, e.g., `comment-region` (with `C-u` it uncomments) to do this quickly.  Binary search is powerful.  Don't even try to guess what might be the problem -- just narrow it down mechanically this way.  You'll isolate the culprit code in no time.